# How to find xyz dimensions as I rotate an object

Tags: mesh, dimensions

So I know that I can press N and I will get a window that shows me the Dimensions of my object. However, these dimensions always remain the same when I rotate the object. How would I find the new XYZ dimensions as my object is being rotated? Would this be bounding box dimensions?

Comment: You'd have to rotate in *Edit Mode* and leave back to *Object Mode* again as far as I know

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos your comment is the true answer. why you wrote this in comment? :)